# Python & matplotlib - changing the color of individual points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change the color of select individual points of a plot after the plot has been drawn.  Here is an example that I have working that changes all the points when clicked.  What I am looking for is to click on a point and to change the colors of specific other points. How do I reference individual points and their colors?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click on points')

line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(5), 'o', picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance

def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    points = tuple(zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))
    print('onpick points:', points,' ind:',ind)
    #if ind == 0:
    thisline.set_color('orange')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

[image: color example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need your artist to be each point instead of ta collection because you want them to behave separately. So, you can iterate over all your points and make many lines, one at a time. This way, changing the plot's color will only affect the selected patch. Follows an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

# simple picking lines
def onpick1(event):
    thisline = event.artist #Get the clicked line OR line collection
    thisline._color = '#DC143C' #Set to new color, in this case must be hsv
    thisline._axes.figure.canvas.draw() #update the plot
    thisline._axes.figure.canvas.flush_events()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
data = rand(10, 2) #Random points for demonstration
for data_point in data:
    line, = ax1.plot(data_point[0], data_point[1], 'o', picker=2, c='yellow')  #2 points tolerance
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Makes sense, but how do you change the color of the point selected and some other specific point also?

Comment: It really depends on which other point you want to select. You would have to create some sort of condition, which when fulfilled, changes other points.

Comment: As an example: Let `line` be the object you are dealing with. You can access the line's position through `line._x`, `line._y`, `line._xy`. If you save all your plots in a list. You could iterate over the list, find the positions, compute the distances relative to clicked object and change the colors of the one's that are at a minimum distance of the selected point. Hopefully this helps and sorry if this is vague. There is no right way to do it. It only depends on the task at hand.